# With which data format can I distribute a big number of small files?

Tags: zip, compression, archive, dataformat

I am about to publish a machine learning dataset. This dataset contains about 170,000 files (png images of 32px x 32px). I first wanted to share them by a zip archive (57.2MB). However, extracting those files takes extremely long (more than 15 minutes - I'm not sure when I started).

Is there a better format to share those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some Benchmarks:

### Experiments / Benchmarks

I used `dtrx` to extract the following and `time dtrx filename` to get the time.

```
Format      File size     Time to extract
.7z          27.7 MB      > 1h
.tar.bz2     29.1 MB      7.18s
.tar.lzma    29.3 MB      6.43s
.xz          29.3 MB      6.56s
.tar.gz      33.3 MB      6.56s
.zip         57.2 MB      > 30min
.jar         70.8 MB      5.64s
.tar        177.9 MB      5.40s
```

Interesting. The extracted content is 47 MB big. Why is `.tar` more than 3 times the size of its content?

Anyway. I think `tar.bz2` might be a good choice.

Comment: tar files use 512-byte blocks for entries, so if a file is less than 512 bytes, it will still take up that amount, with the rest filled in with zeros. Also each file is preceded by a 512-byte block for the file metadata. So if the files are about 340 bytes each, then the tar file would be three times the size of the original files. (Note that drives use blocks as well, so the files may be taking up even more space on the drive.)

Answer (score 0):

Try .tar.xz - better compression ratio but a little slower to extract than .tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Just use tar.gz at the lowest compression level (just to get rid of the tar zeros between files). png files are already compressed, so there is no point in trying to compress them further. (Though you can use various tools to try to minimize the size of each png file before putting them into the distribution.)